# cant get code to print until second iteration

Tags: c#

Having trouble getting my code to print when the user hits the "calculate button." Only when they click it a second time will the print be output. Any thoughts? I assume its  a logic error with my if/else statements and where my print statements are but I haven't been able to figure it out. Should I construct another method to parse through the input then send a value back to do my calculations?

```
   private void calcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 //declare drink variables

        double cappuccino = 3.25, espresso = 3.5, latte = 3.00, icedLatte = 3.75, icedCappuccino = 3.75;

        //declare coffee bag variables

        double pounder = 9.99, half = 5.99, third = 3.99;

        //other local variables

        double quantity;


        //parse input from user on quantity of goods
        double.TryParse(quantityTextBox.Text, out quantity);

        //series of else if statements used to determine which radio button is keyed by user



        itemAmountLabel.Text = value.ToString("N");
        subTotal += value;

        // surchargeCalc(surcharge);

        //Calculate tax
        tax = taxRate * (subTotal + totalSurcharge);

        total = tax + subTotal + totalSurcharge;

        subtotalLabel.Text = subTotal.ToString("N");
        totalLabel.Text = total.ToString("N");
        taxLabel.Text = tax.ToString("N");


        if (cappuccinoRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            value = quantity * cappuccino;
            return;
        }

        else if (espressoRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            value = quantity * espresso;
            return;
        }
        else if (latteRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            value = quantity * latte;
            return;
        }
        else if (icedLatteRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            value = quantity * icedLatte;
            return;
        }
        else if (icedCappuccinoRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            value = quantity * icedCappuccino;
            return;
        }
        else if (onePoundBagRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            value = quantity * pounder;
            return;
        }
        else if (halfPoungBagRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            value = quantity * half;
            if (surchargeCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                surcharge++;
            }
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            value = quantity * third;
            if (surchargeCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                surcharge++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Webforms, WPF, winforms? What type of program is this? Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: It's not printing because you don't have any print statements in your code.

Comment: Is that all of the code for `calcButton_Click`?  I don't see a closing bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be writing the value out here:

```
itemAmountLabel.Text = value.ToString("N");
```

Before you then do all of your calculations.

You should really write the output at the end of your method, once you have finished calculations.

Watch out for your return statements when you move this, as if you return before this line, it still won't write.

As all of the returns are in a big if-elseif block, you can remove them.